# Recursive relationship issues

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I'm creating a database which has a table called employee. This one has a recursive relationship, a employee can manage one or more employees, and an employee can be managed by at least one employee. 
The problem is that i don't really know how to create properly the new table. This new table is called manage (came from that recursivity because its a relation N to N) but i don't know how to put the foreign key to check if it is a manager or not. This is what i've done.

```
CREATE TABLE employee
 (id_employee VARCHAR (25) primary key,
 telephone CHAR (9) NOT NULL, 
 name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=INNODB;

 CREATE TABLE manage
 (id_employee VARCHAR (25),
 id_manager VARCHAR (25),
 primary key (id_employee, id_manager),
 foreign key (id_employee) references employee (id_employee),
 foreign key (id_manager) references employee (id_employee) 
 )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: A manager is an `id_employee` in the `manage.id_manager` column. You've got that as a FK already. There's no other bits that say "is a manager" or not.

Comment: So is that the correct way to do it? I mean, will it not just put twice the same value from id_employee at any case?

Comment: Normally an employee has, at most, only one manager. Otherwise, things get confusing.

Comment: What you have is fine, despite the business case confusion with employing too many managers :-). Note, its not really recursion, just a self referencing table.